# How to resolve 'Timeout expired' error while connecting to External (ODBC) database in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, netezza

I am working on an Access application which needs to establish a connection to an External database (Netezza database). I am currently using VBA code with ADODB objects to connect to the server.
Whenever I execute the code, 'Timeout expired' error occurs.
I have tried to reset the Timecounter to 180 seconds. Still the error is not resolved.

**This is the code I've been using:**

```
Private Sub CONNECT_Click()

Dim openSQL As ADODB.Connection

Set openSQL = New ADODB.Connection

openSQL.ConnectionTimeout = 180

openSQL.Open "odbc;servername=xxx;dsn=xxx;database=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;port=xxx"

openSQL.Close

End Sub
```

**I've also tried the below code:**

```
Private Sub Modify_Click()


Dim objConnection As ADODB.Connection

Dim objRecordSet As ADODB.Recordset

Dim strConnectionString As String


Set objConnection = New ADODB.Connection

Set objRecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset

'Define the Odbc connection string.

  strConnectionString = "odbc;servername=xxx;dsn=xxx;database=xxx;uid=xxx;pwd=xxx;port=xx"

  'Instantiate the Connection object and open a database connection.
  'var cnn

  objConnection.Open strConnectionString
  'objConnection.Open "dsn=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"


   Dim strSQL As String

  'Define SQL SELECT statement.

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table_1 (col1,col2,col3, col4) VALUES ('" & Form1.col1 & "', '" & Form1.col2 & "', '" & Form1.col3 & "', '" & Form1.col4 & "');"

  'Use the Execute method to issue a SQL query to database.
  cnn.Execute strSQL

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you connect, from the same machine, by any other method?  If you set timeout to 0 it will never timeout.  This is a good way of testing very slow connections.

Comment: I've tried to change the value to 0, even then the issue is not resolved.